# Clean way of taking first argument without modifiying args

Tags: rust, iterator

This program should take arguments like so: `<command> n1 n2 n3...` e.g `mode 1 2 3 3 4`. I want to store the `<command>` argument string and pass the rest of the arguments into a constructor for parsing.

```rust
fn main() {
    let args = args();

    let command = args.skip(1).next().unwrap_or_else(|| {
        eprintln!("Command not found; expected one of \"mode\", \"mean\", \"median\" \"range\"");
        process::exit(1);
    });

    let set = DataSet::from_args(args).unwrap_or_else(|err| {
        eprintln!("error parsing values: {}", err);
        process::exit(1);
    });

    match command.to_lowercase().trim() {
        "mode" => println!("{:?}", set.mode()),
        _ => eprintln!("Command not recognised: \"{}\"", command),
    }
}
```

This code doesn't work because `args.skip(1).next()...` consumes `args` by adapting it into a `Skip`, so when I try to call `DataSet::from_args(args)` It is invalid because it was moved into `skip`.

What is the best way to achieve this? I've heard the itertools library could provide an `nth` method for `Args` but I'd prefer to do this without.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, [std has `nth()` method](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.nth): you can use `nth(1)` instead of `skip(1).next()`.

Second, [`Iterator` is implemented for `&mut Iterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.60.0/src/core/iter/traits/iterator.rs.html#3676-3691). So you can just call `skip()` on `&mut args`. There is even a method for that: [`by_ref()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.by_ref):

```rust
    let command = args.by_ref().skip(1).next().unwrap_or_else(|| {
        eprintln!("Command not found; expected one of \"mode\", \"mean\", \"median\" \"range\"");
        process::exit(1);
    });
```

Comment: Wow, don't know how I missed that. Thanks!